# does anyone know where i am going wrong? the first 2 lines is where the error is..... Extra argument 'error' in call

Tags: ios, json, parsing, xcode7

Here is my code that i am getting an error with:

```
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {

            let userId = parseJSON["userID"] as? String
            if(userId != nil)
            {
            } else {
            //display alert message
                let userId = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Problem", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil)

                myAlert.addAction(okAction);

                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

can someone let me know what is wrong with the bold text please?

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? (Don't try to make part of your code **bold** because that just messes up the formatting.) Exactly what error are you getting? Copy it from Xcode's Issue navigator and paste it into your question.

Comment: It would help if you told us why, or why you think it is going wrong.

Comment: This is the line i am getting an error: 

var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

Comment: Extra argument 'error' in call

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied some sample code that was written for Swift 1.x.

In Swift 2.x, the `error` parameter in most APIs is replaced by Swift's native error handling. Rewrite it like this:

```
do {
    var json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
catch {
    // Handle error here
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the error parameter and handle error with try:

```
do {
let object:AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
} catch let caught as ErrorType {
completeWith(nil, response, caught)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, `JSONObjectWithData` doesn't take an `error` argument. It throws an error instead.

```
func f(data: NSData) {
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers)
        guard let parseJSON = json as? NSDictionary else {
            print("JSON wasn't an object")
            return
        }
        guard let userId = parseJSON["userID"] as? String else {
            print("userId absent or not a string")
            return
        }
        print("got userId \(userId)")
    } catch {
        print("Could not parse data as JSON: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: what code shall i get rid of to replace it? could you possible write out what i need to put in please

Comment: You can use the code I posted as a template and replace the print statements with whatever your app actually needs to do (like display an alert view or whatever).